# Branch.io event logs not showing up in dashboard but install events are

Tags: branch.io

I am using the react native branch deep linking library to integrate branch.io into my app. It is showing install events in my live view on branch but when I do any sort of event logging using the library it does not show up.

Inside my xcode console it is showing;

Debug: Network finish operation https://api.branch.io/v2/event/standard 0.825s. Status 200 error (null).
{"branch_view_enabled":false}.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and seeing the same thing in console. I can't even set up referrals because the events aren't coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently all the logging events uses the v2 endpoint and doesn't show up in the dashboards...

Data partner integration also doesn't seem to work...

The only way to get the data is by exporting it.